# how do i define 24 bit array in c++?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

how do i define 24 bit array in c++? (variable declaration)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.  Is the overall size 24-bits or each element?  Also, what type of data should it be?  Bitfield, numeric, string?

Comment: each element should be 24 bit (and this is also the type of data)

Answer (score 13):

There is no 24-bit variable type in C++.

You can use a bitpacked struct:

```
struct ThreeBytes {
    uint32_t value:24;
};
```

But it is not guaranteed that `sizeof ThreeBytes == 3`.

You can also just use `uint32_t` or `sint32_t`, depending on what you need.

Another choice is to use `std::bitset`:

```
typedef std::bitset<24> ThreeBytes;
```

Then make an array out of that:

```
ThreeBytes *myArray = new ThreeBytes[10];
```

Of course, if you really just need "three bytes", you can make an array of arrays:

```
typedef uint8_t ThreeBytes[3];
```

*Note that `uint8_t` and friends are non-standard, and are used simply for clarification.*

Answer (score 2):

An unsigned byte array of 3 bytes is 24 bits. Depending on how you are planning to use it, it could do.

```
unsigned char arrayname[3]
```

As @GMan points out you should be aware that [it's not 100% of all systems](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Data_Types_Reference) that has 8 bits chars.

Comment: A byte (`char`) is not necessarily 8 bits.

Comment: @GMan, That is incorrect, according to the C standard.  I'll have to look at the C++ standard.

Comment: @strager: A `char` is not necessarily 8 bits in both C and C++. It is necessarily *at least* 8 bits, but is not necessarily *exactly* 8 bits.

Comment: According to 5.3.3, `sizeof(char)==1` always.  However, it defines that the number of bits in a byte is implementation defined.  So I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @strager: sizeof(char) = 1 byte, not one *octet*. :)

Comment: No, it is actually correct. The C standard defines the CHAR_BIT macro and mandates a minimum size of 8, but also allows for larger sizes

5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>
"Their implementation-deﬁned values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign."

Comment: I must have misread the C standard somewhere, too, perhaps mistaking the `#define CHAR_BIT 8` example as 'law'.

Comment: But ...  who cares.  I use `uint8_t` anyway.  ;P  It's portable across GCC and VC++ anyway.

Comment: @stager: And in C99, given `stdint.h` it is standard.

Comment: @GMan, Yup, and Boost has it for C++ if necessary (though it's not as convenient due to silly namespaces).

Comment: @strager: You can also make your own `stdint.h` that includes Boost's then has a series of using-directives. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to perform bitwise operations on them, then simply use an integral type that has at least 24 bits. An `int` is 32 bits on most platforms, so an `int` may be suitable for this purpose.

**EDIT:** Since you actually wanted an *array* of 24 bit variables, the most straightforward way to do this is to create an array of `int`s or `long`s (as long as it's an integral data type that contains at least 24 bits) and treat each element as though it was 24 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your purpose (for example, if you are concerned that using a 32bit type might waste too much memory), you might also consider creating an array of bytes with three times the length.

I used to do that a lot for storing RGB images. To access the n'th element, you would have to multiply by three and then add zero, one or two depending on which "channel" out of the element you wanted. Of course, if you want to access all 24 bits as one integer, this approach requires some additional arithmetics.

So simply `unsigned char myArray[ELEMENTS * 3];` where ELEMENTS is the number of 24bit elements that you want.

Comment: Reading the comments to the answer above, my approach is obviously also flawed in the way that a char is not necessarily 8 bits.. but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Use [bitset](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset.html) or [bitvector](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitvector.html) if they are supported on your platform. (They are :) )

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::bitset<24> > myArray;
```